# TypeScript not liking HTMLHeadingElement | null assignment

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to follow some basic JavaScript tutorials, but do them in TypeScript using ESLint as well. I am trying to get the following code:

```js
const myHeading: HTMLHeadingElement | null = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent = 'Hello, World!';
```

However, `tsc` reports that *`Object is possibly 'null'`*. **I am not sure how to get past this with TypeScript**.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src/typescript",
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/typescript/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.ts.spec"]
}
```

This is also my `.eslintrc.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  'env': {
    'browser': true,
    'es2020': true,
  },
  'extends': [
    'google',
  ],
  'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 11,
    'sourceType': 'module',
  },
  'plugins': [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  'rules': {
  },
};
```

[image]

Comment: Well... yeah. You told it (with `| null`) that it might be null. So of course when you try to access a property, it warns you that it might be null. You need to check `if( myHeading) { ... }` to ensure it's not null.

Comment: I am not following. Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can be `null`, you just have to if check it before using it:

```
const myHeading: HTMLHeadingElement | null = document.querySelector('h1');
if(myHeading){
   myHeading.textContent = 'Hello, World!';
}
```

Comment: I will try this out

Comment: This was the correct answer. Thank you for being helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I had to change my typing to be this in order for it to work for me.

```js
const myHeading: HTMLHeadingElement = document.querySelector('h1');
if (myheading) {
  myHeading.textContent = 'Hello, World!';
};
```

This satisfied `tsc` so that the `myHeading` would not be typed as `null`.

Comment: You're not very helpful @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Don't put alternate types it is either the one type you want or null. Just check for null using if statement.  BTW HtmlElement type are used in JavaScript too. So this is not a Typescript specific question other than syntax

Comment: @FilBot3 *I'm* not helpful? I literally gave you the answer in a comment within three minutes of you posting the question, but despite that you went and "solved" it yourself by doing the worst possible thing you can do in TypeScript. k.

Comment: Thank you @JohnPeters. I'll remove that from my answer above. I was not quite following earlier what was being said. Now that I have seen it I understand what was being said and asked of me.